# extends from generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

What wrong in last row?

```
interface I1<T>{}

 class Class1 implements I1{}
 class Class2 extends  Class1 implements I1{}         //valid

 class Class3 implements I1<Number>{}
 class Class4 extends  Class3 implements I1<Number>{}  //valid

 class Class5 implements I1<Number>{}
 class Class6 extends  Class5 implements I1<Integer>{}  //not valid

 class Class7 implements I1{}
 class Class8 extends  Class7 implements I1<Number>{}         // not valid

 class Class9 implements I1<Number>{}
 class Class10 extends  Class9 implements I1{}         //  not valid !!!
```

Why I cannot make so?

I saw it in book, but there are not explanation of this thing - only for information.

**P.S.**

exception text:

```
java: GenericsTest.I1 cannot be inherited with different arguments:
<java.lang.Integer> and <java.lang.Number>
```

Comment: do you get "repeated interface"? or something like "cannot inherit with different type"?

Comment: @guido There is a special compilation error for this. Something like "ClassName cannot be inherited with different arguments".

Comment: @Radiodef oh yeah thx, I meant that but faulty memory scrambled the wording (no compiler at hand)

Comment: @Radiodef   please read topic one more time. I added information

Comment: @guido please read topic one more time. I added information

Comment: The answer is the same for the things you've added.

Comment: I don't understand at this case

Comment: research class 9 and class10

Comment: `Class8` is trying to implement an interface twice with different type arguments and `Class10` is the same as `Class2`. (Did you mean for `Class10` to extend `Class9`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two points to understanding this:

- Java generics are normally type-invariant. This means that, for example, an `I1<Number>` and an `I1<Integer>` are distinct types. For most purposes, they are unrelated, despite that Integer extends Number.
- If an interface is declared as being implemented on a superclass, it can be declared to be implemented again on a subclass. It's redundant but it's allowed.

Now, what is not allowed is implementing an interface twice, where the generic type of the interface is different.

For example, this is not allowed:

```
class NotAllowed implements I1<String>, I1<Integer> {}
```

The types of `I1` are erased at run time so you cannot do that. At run time there is not really a difference between an `I1<String>` and an `I1<Integer>`. Both of them become just `I1`.

Your example with `Class5` and `Class6` is not allowed for the same reason as the above `NotAllowed` is not allowed. It implements the same interface twice but with different generic types.

If it were allowed, it would be paradoxical, because for example given the following:

```
interface Face<T> {
    public void method(T t);
}
```

If I then implement this twice with different types, it would imply there must be two generically-typed implementations of `method`:

```
class Implementation
implements Face<String>, Face<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void method(String s) {}
    @Override
    public void method(Integer i) {}
}
```

This is paradoxical because erasure also dictates that both implementations of `method` will become identical at run time. You cannot have methods with identical signatures declared in the same class so it's not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Class1 implements I1{}
class Class2 extends  Class1 implements I1{}
```

This one is obvious, it means that Class2 implements I1{}. It does it explicitly by saying `implements I1{}` but also implicitly by extending `Class1`, which implements `I1{}` as well. There's no problem since they both implement the same interface, it's not ambiguous.

```
class Class3 implements I1<Number>{}
class Class4 extends  Class3 implements I1<Number>{}
```

This is the same flavor as above. It says `Class4` implements `I1<Number>`. It's specified implicitly and explicitly as above. But it's not ambiguous, it's `I1<Number>`

Of course, it's redundant because it uses two way simultaneously to define that `Class4` implements `I1<Number>`. You could just do `class Class4 extends  Class3` and it'd be exactly the same.

Now with this one it's different:

```
class Class5 implements I1<Number>{}
class Class6 extends  Class5 implements I1<Integer>{}
```

It says `Class6` is implementing both `I1<Integer>` (explicitly) and `I1<Number>` (implicitly through extending `Class5`). It can't be at the same time. Imagine for example that I1 has a method: `public X something()`. It's signature in `I1<Number>` would be `public Number something()` and in `I1<Integer>` it would be `public Integer something()`. This would lead to a duplicate method. It's therefore invalid. If you implement a generic interface, you can only implement it once, no matter the generic type.

I hope this helps illustrate why it's invalid.

**EDIT**

First, understand that `I1` is semantically the same as `I1<Object>`.
Then, understand that `I1<A>` is not the same as `I1<B>`
Also, understand that all your invalid examples can be summarized (for reasons explained above) with:

```
class X implements I1<A>, I1<B>
```

Why is that invalid? Because it may create ambiguity in the signatures. If `I1` looked like this:

```
public interface I1<T> {
public T something();
}
```

Then `X` would have to look something like:

```
class X implements I1<A>, I1<B> {
    public A something() { return null; }
    public B something() { return null; }
}
```

Now, if I did:

```
X x = new X();
x.something();
```

Which of the two methods is is calling? You can't tell, because it is ambiguous. The Java language just doesn't give you the opportunity to define ambiguous APIs. Therefore, you can't implement both `I1<A>` and `I1<B>`.

Answer (score 0):

because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) implementing one interface with two different generic parameter is impossible.