# generics and keyword final

Tags: java, generics, final

Whu Do it is a non-valid construction

```
class A <T extends  String & Comparable<T>>{}
```

out:

```
java: java.lang.Comparable cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T> and <java.lang.String>
```

but it is valid

```
class A <T extends  Number & Comparable<T>>{}
```

I noiced that it is related with String is final but Number - not.

But T String is valid at first case I think. Why not?

Comment: You didn't get the first error message from the first piece of code. Did it really say `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BaseFoo cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T,X.Bar<T>> and <T,X.Foo<T>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436415/basefoo-cannot-be-inherited-with-different-arguments-t-x-bart-and-t-x-foo)

Comment: @EJP I am corrected mistake. For integer similar behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is, `String` class already implements `Comparable<String>`, while `Number` class doesn't. So, with that bound, `T` would be implementing both `Comparable<String>` and `Comparable<T>`, which is not allowed.

A class cannot extend from or implement different parameterized instantiation of a generic type.

Comment: just for information. more in details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281553/extends-from-generic-interfaces